# Matlab - Speeding up Nested For-Loops

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop

I'm working on a function with three nested for loops that is way too slow for its intended use. The bottleneck is clearly the looping part - almost 100 % of the execution time is spent in the innermost loop.
The function takes a 2d matrix called `rM` as input and returns a 3d matrix called `ec`:

```
rows = size(rM, 1);
cols = size(rM, 2);

%preallocate.
ec = zeros(rows+1, cols, numRiskLevels);
ec(1, :, :) = 100;

for risk = minRisk:stepRisk:maxRisk;
    for c = 1:cols,
        for r = 2:rows+1,
            ec(r, c, risk) = ec(r-1, c, risk) * (1 + risk * rM(r-1, c));
        end
    end
end
```

Any help on speeding up the for loops would be appreciated...

Comment: It looks like the second loop could be vectorized: remove `for c = 1:cols` and its `end`, and replace `c` by `:` in the innermost line. That should help reduce time

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks for your suggestion. I implemented it, but interestingly that made the code run even slower than before.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Perhaps using a different calculation rather than trying to speed the current one up is a viable solution?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin As far as I know the calculation can't really be done another way, so I guess I'm gonna have to stick with this one..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the inner loop is slowest, while it is also near-impossible to vectorize. As every iteration directly depends on the previous one.

The outer two are possible:

```
clc;
rM = rand(50);

rows = size(rM, 1);
cols = size(rM, 2);

minRisk = 1;
stepRisk = 1;
maxRisk = 100;
numRiskLevels = maxRisk/stepRisk;

%preallocate.
ec = zeros(rows+1, cols, numRiskLevels);
ec(1, :, :) = 100;

riskArray = (minRisk:stepRisk:maxRisk)';
tic
for r = 2:rows+1
    tmp = riskArray * rM(r-1, :);
    tmp = permute(tmp, [3 2 1]);
    ec(r, :, :) = ec(r-1, :, :) .* (1 + tmp);
end
toc


%preallocate.
ec2 = zeros(rows+1, cols, numRiskLevels);
ec2(1, :, :) = 100;
tic
for risk = minRisk:stepRisk:maxRisk;
    for c = 1:cols
        for r = 2:rows+1
            ec2(r, c, risk) = ec2(r-1, c, risk) * (1 + risk * rM(r-1, c));
        end
    end
end
toc

all(all(all(ec == ec2)))
```

But to my surprise, the vectorized code is indeed slower. (But maybe someone can improve the code, so I figured I leave it her for you.)

Comment: +1 Thanks for your suggestions..I'm also very surprised as to why the vectorized versions are slower than the loops (see update in my question).

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried to vectorize the outer loop, and actually noticed a significant speed increase. Of course it is hard to judge the speed of a script without knowing (the size of) the inputs but I would say this is a good starting point:

```
% Here you can change the input parameters
riskVec = 1:3:120;
rM = rand(50);


%preallocate and calculate non vectorized solution
ec2 = zeros(size(rM,2)+1, size(rM,1), max(riskVec));
ec2(1, :, :) = 100;
tic
for risk = riskVec
    for c = 1:size(rM,2)
        for r = 2:size(rM,1)+1
            ec2(r, c, risk) = ec2(r-1, c, risk) * (1 + risk * rM(r-1, c));
        end
    end
end
t1=toc;

%preallocate and calculate vectorized solution
ec = zeros(size(rM,2)+1, size(rM,1), max(riskVec));
ec(1, :, :) = 100;
tic
for c = 1:size(rM,2)
    for r = 2:size(rM,1)+1
        ec(r, c, riskVec) = ec(r-1, c, riskVec) .* reshape(1 + riskVec * rM(r-1, c),[1 1 length(riskVec)]);
    end
end
t2=toc;

% Check whether the vectorization is done correctly and show the timing results
if ec(:) == ec2(:)
    t1
    t2
end
```

The given output is:

```
 t1 =

    0.1288


t2 =

    0.0408
```

So for this `riskVec` and `rM` it is about 3 times as fast as the non-vectorized solution.

Comment: +1 Thanks Dennis, I'll try out your solution later and see how fast it  is with my actual input data.